# JGit - Re-order/remove commits in Master branch before push to Upstream

Tags: java, git, jgit, git-remote, git-rewrite-history

I'm currently designing an app that uses a GIT repo as a persistence unit for a set of property files, the app handles the maintainance of the property files in a test repo before publishing (pushing) the changes to a production repo.

The app uses JGit to integrate with the Git repository.

The complication here is that the users must be able to add and remove commits from the test repo before pushing a `release` to production, each commit maps to changes in an individual property file. All commits that are not pushed to the remote production repository must stay `un-pushed`.

So imagine the next situation:
Test repo has 4 commits
`c1-c2-c3-c4`

But the user chooses to only push commits `c1` and `c4`.

The expected production commits after the push should be `c1-c4` but the commits that were not pushed to production repo should stay in the test repo.

I've had a look at a few different native GIT solutions but cant really seam to achieve the expected output with JGIT, here are a few solutions I've looked at:

- JGit Rebase: JGIT doesn't support `DROP` actions on commits, `EDIT` didn't work either
- JGit Cherry Pick: Create a separate branch for test values, then cherrypick the values that want to be published to production onto master. But how to deal with commits left in separate branch?
- Also tried with JGit reset, JGit revert, etc.. but none of the native git operations furfil all of the project requirements.

I guess my question is, does anyone know of a native git operation that JGit supports that will achieve the expected functionality?

I've come to realise there is little or no documentation regarding JGit, the best place to check the JGit api is to look at [these examples](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook). If there are more docs out there that I have not found, I'd also appreciate a link.

Comment: Please clarify what should be done with the 'un-pushed' commits. Do they need to be kept for later or can they be discarded?

Comment: If you cherry-pick the commits to be published, you can reset the branch to master, thus discarding all un-published commits. If they are to be kept, cherry-pick them onto a temporary branch (whose starting point is where you branched from master) and reset the working branch to this temporary branch.